# Displaying a navbar on the same level with the title and logo of the page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I created a navbar using bootstrap that is below the logo and the title of my page. 
[image: navbar]

But when it comes to smaller devices (mobiles), I'd like to put the collapsed navbar on the same level as my title and logo are, but I can't figure out how to do that. Here is what I have so far :

[image]

```
<div id="menu" class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <h1 style="text-align: center;margin-top:0;">
    <a href="#/" style="color:white;text-decoration:none">
      <img id="logo" src = "images/logo.svg" width="20px">
    </a>
    <a id="title" href="#/" style="color:white;font-family: fantasy;text-decoration:none">Title of the page </a>
  </h1>
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-navbar-collapse" ng-controller="HeaderCtrl">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
      <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/about') }"><a href="#/about">aa</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">bb<b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">aa</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">bb</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">cc</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/aa') }"><a href="#/aa">cc</a></li>
      <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/dd') }"><a href="#/dd">dd</a></li>
      <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/ee') }"><a href="#/ee">ee</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my little snippet : https://jsfiddle.net/Lasjo4xz/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
   h1 {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
   }
   ...
}
```

the `position:absolute` will make the header (h1 with img) lose it's occupied space so that it can be on top of the nav div. I find this to be a simple solution because if you wanted to float the navbar div, it may cause problem with widths

`left:0; and right:0;` make sure the element is horizontally centered.

Comment: How thank you, it works like a charm ! And thanks also for the explanations, I am a complete noob to css but I like to understand!

Comment: happy to help! please go ahead and accept the answer by clicking the check mark under the votes count. have a nice day and good luck

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and simple fix:

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
    #menu {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
```

The `h1` is a block element. This means it always occupies the full available width of the container.

The same thing goes for the div containing the menu icon.

They are on different rows (stacked vertically) because they are both block elements.

You could try switching them to `inline-block` in the media query. That will line them up together. Or you could use flex.